# How to take derivative of hypergeometric function with time-dependent arguments?

Tags: derivatives, hypergeometric-function

I have a hypergeometric function with two time dependent arguments

${}_2F_1(a(t),b(t),\frac{1}{2},x)$

and I want to take the derivative with respect to $t$. 
To be specific, I have

$a(t) = \frac{-\sqrt{1-\frac{4it}{v_0}}-1}{4}$

$b(t) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{4it}{v_0}}-1}{4}$

($i$ is the imaginary unit, $v_0 = constant$, and after taking the derivative I will set $t=0$.
Is it possible to do this and find a sensible, analytic answer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $a(0) = -1/2$ and $b(0) = 0$. There is a simple closed form because we need to take the derivative of ${_2 F_1}$ wrt a parameter only at zero, where termwise differentiation gives
$$\lim_{b \to 0} \frac {(b)_k - (0)_k} b =
\cases {\Gamma(k) & $k > 0$ \\ 0 & $k = 0$},\\
\frac d {db} \, {_2 F_1}(a, b; c; x) \bigg\rvert_{b = 0} =
\frac {a x} c \, {_3 F_2}(1, 1, a + 1; 2, c + 1; x).$$
The other partial derivative disappears because ${_2 F_1}(a, 0; c; x) = 1$. Therefore
$$\frac d {dt} \, {_2 F_1}(a(t), b(t); 1/2; x) \bigg\rvert_{t = 0} =
-b'(0) x \, {_3 F_2}(1, 1, 1/2; 2, 3/2; x) = \\
\frac i {2 v_0} (\ln(1 - x) + \sqrt x \,(\ln(1 + \sqrt x) - \ln(1 - \sqrt x))).$$

Comment: Great, thanks very much for such a clear answer.